# How to store object model in database?

Tags: java, database, orm

I am new in ORM and databases. I need to store this object model:
I have class Receipe, which contains one or more lists of ingredients with names. Eg, receipe is Pizza, it contains two list of ingredients:  "dough" [eggs, floor...] and "stuffing" [meat, cheese, onion...].

I don't know how to store Ingredients List. Can you give me example with any ORM annotations?

```
class Receipe {

String name;
String receipeText;

//String - name of ingredients list
HashMap<String, List<Ingredient> ingredientsLists;    

}
```

Comment: which ORM hibernate ??

Comment: Have you tried to make a class with the fields 'String Name' and 'List<Ingredient> Ingredients' and replace the HashMap with it.

Comment: Ie class IngredientsList { String Name; List<Ingredient> Ingredients}. And then Receipe will be {... List<IngredientsList> lists } ?

Comment: @DarkDarker Yes, that is normally how I would do it. Just remember to add the name and receipetext also

Comment: @NiksTyagi, I will use ormlite or openjpa